# Heartbeat (haksock)

Tags: c#, networking

I've recently been working on a small project to provide a simple heartbeat between server and client applications.  Pretty happy with it, just wondering if it could function better (I know it could use cleaning, and a standard naming convention, I like to code quick and dirty then clean up)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Haksock.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace HakSock {
  public class Heart : IDisposable{
    public sealed class ConnectionStateEventArgs : EventArgs {
        public ConnectionState ConnectionState { get; private set; }
        public ConnectionStateEventArgs(ConnectionState connectionState) {
            ConnectionState = connectionState;
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler<ConnectionStateEventArgs> ConnectionStateChanged;
    #region Globals
    private System.Timers.Timer Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private IPEndPoint ipep;
    bool isServer;
    public bool connected = false;
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    private DateTime lastUpdate;
    private Socket udpServerSocket;
    private EndPoint ep;
    public TimeSpan timeSinceLastHeartbeat;
    private ConnectionState _connectionState = ConnectionState.Disconnected;
    public ConnectionState ConnectionState {
        get { return _connectionState; }
        set {
            if (value != _connectionState) {
                _connectionState = value;
                var tmp = ConnectionStateChanged;
                if (tmp != null)
                    tmp(this, new ConnectionStateEventArgs(value));
            }
        }
    }
    public bool IsDisposed {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region constructor/destructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of a Heart
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isserver">Specifies whether this is the server</param>
    /// <param name="autostart">specifies if the Heart should start on creation</param>
    /// <param name="port">Specifies the port (this will set the server port if isserver is true, else will set the client port)</param>
    public Heart(bool isserver, bool autostart, int port = 10000) {
        ;
        Timer.Interval = 1500;
        Timer.AutoReset = true;
        isServer = isserver;
        this.ConnectionStateChanged += Heart_ConnectionStateChanged;
        if (isserver) {
            ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            Timer.Elapsed += srTimer_Elapsed;
            udpServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpServerSocket.Bind(ep);
            udpServerSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, ref ep, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), udpServerSocket);
            udpServerSocket.Ttl = 255;
        } else {
            Timer.Elapsed += clTimer_Elapsed;
            ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
        }
        if (autostart)
            startBeating();

    }

    private void Heart_ConnectionStateChanged(object sender, ConnectionStateEventArgs e) {
        if (e.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Connected)
            connected = true;
        else
            connected = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of a Heart
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timespan">Specifies the timespan between each beat</param>
    /// <param name="isserver">Specifies whether this is the server</param>
    /// <param name="autostart">specifies if the Heart should start on creation</param>
    /// <param name="port">Specifies the port (this will set the server port if isserver is true, else will set the client port)</param>
    public Heart(double timespan = 1500, bool isserver = false, bool autostart = true,int port = 10000) {
        Timer.Interval = timespan;
        isServer = isserver;
        ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        if (isserver) {
            Timer.Elapsed += srTimer_Elapsed;
            udpServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpServerSocket.Bind(ep);
            udpServerSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, ref ep, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), udpServerSocket);
            udpServerSocket.Ttl = 255;
        } else {
            Timer.Elapsed += clTimer_Elapsed;
            ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
        }
        if (autostart)
            startBeating();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events

    #region handled events
    private void clTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        try {
            SendUdpPacket();
            ConnectionState = ConnectionState.Connected;
        } catch {
            ConnectionState = ConnectionState.Disconnected;
        }
    }
    private void srTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        // Calculate the Timespan since the Last Update from the Client.
        timeSinceLastHeartbeat = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - lastUpdate;

        // Set Lable Text depending of the Timespan
        if (timeSinceLastHeartbeat > TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timer.Interval))
            ConnectionState = ConnectionState.Disconnected;
        else
            ConnectionState = ConnectionState.Connected;
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing) {
            IsDisposed = true;
        }
        Dispose(disposing);
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        this.stopBeating();
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion

    #region Beat
    /// <summary>
    /// Start the Hearbeat
    /// </summary>
    public void startBeating() {
        Timer.Start();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Stop the Heartbeat
    /// </summary>
    public void stopBeating() {
        Timer.Stop();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a packet to the HeartServer
    /// </summary>
    private void SendUdpPacket() {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        Socket udpClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("lubdub");
        udpClientSocket.SendTo(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, ipep);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Recieves a packet from the HeartClient
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="iar"></param>
    void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult iar) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        EndPoint tempRemoteEP = (EndPoint)sender;
        Socket remote = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        int recv = remote.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref tempRemoteEP);
        string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, recv);
        Console.WriteLine(stringData);
        lastUpdate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        if (!this.IsDisposed) {
            udpServerSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, ref ep, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), udpServerSocket);
        }
    }

    private class ConnectionStateChangedEventArgs {
        private ConnectionState value;

        public ConnectionStateChangedEventArgs(ConnectionState value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
}
```

**Enums.cs**

```
namespace HakSock {
 public enum ConnectionState {
    Connected,
    Disconnected
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to C#6?

Comment: @RobH I'm using VS2015 so yes.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would have a bug related to the `protected Dispose(bool)` method

> ```
> protected void Dispose(bool disposing) {
>     if (disposing) {
>         IsDisposed = true;
>     }
>     Dispose(disposing);
> }
> ```

if you would  use it. Luckily you don't use it, otherwise you would get likely get some kind of overflow exception.

<s>So please remove this method so you won't trap inside the trap.</s>

At a second thought it may be better to keep it after doing it right, because the `ReceiveData()` method relies on the `IsDisposed` property.

---

> ```
> private void Heart_ConnectionStateChanged(object sender, ConnectionStateEventArgs e) {
>     if (e.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Connected)
>         connected = true;
>     else
>         connected = false;
> }
> ```

this should be simplified to just

```
private void Heart_ConnectionStateChanged(object sender, ConnectionStateEventArgs e) {
    connected = e.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Connected;
}
```

---

The `Heart` class could use some constructor chaining, which removes some duplicated code.

So this

> ```
> public Heart(bool isserver, bool autostart, int port = 10000) {
>     ;
>     Timer.Interval = 1500;
>     Timer.AutoReset = true;
>     isServer = isserver;
>     this.ConnectionStateChanged += Heart_ConnectionStateChanged;
>     if (isserver) {
>         ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
>         Timer.Elapsed += srTimer_Elapsed;
>         udpServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
>         udpServerSocket.Bind(ep);
>         udpServerSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, ref ep, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), udpServerSocket);
>         udpServerSocket.Ttl = 255;
>     } else {
>         Timer.Elapsed += clTimer_Elapsed;
>         ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
>     }
>     if (autostart)
>         startBeating();
>
> }
> ```

would become this

```
public Heart(bool isserver, bool autostart, int port = 10000) 
        :this(1500, isserver, autostart, port)
{}
```

---

Seeing something like this

> ```
> private System.Timers.Timer Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
> private IPEndPoint ipep;
> bool isServer;
> ```

just doesn't look right. You should always add access modifiers to your properties and methods making the indent more clear.

---

Please read regarding the use of regions: [Are #regions an antipattern or code smell?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell)

---

> ```
> public ConnectionState ConnectionState {
>     get { return _connectionState; }
>     set {
>         if (value != _connectionState) {
>             _connectionState = value;
>             var tmp = ConnectionStateChanged;
>             if (tmp != null)
>                 tmp(this, new ConnectionStateEventArgs(value));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I don't really like that setter, it is doing IMO to much. You should consider to extract the raising of the event to a separate method like so

```
protected void OnConnectionStateChanged(ConnectionStateEventArgs e)
{
    var stateChanged = ConnectionStateChanged;
    if (stateChanged != null)
    {
        stateChanged(this, e));
    }
}
```

to be called form the setter like so

```
    set {
        if (value != _connectionState) {
            OnConnectionStateChanged(new ConnectionStateEventArgs(value));
        }
    }
```

---

> ```
> private class ConnectionStateChangedEventArgs {
>     private ConnectionState value;
>
>     public ConnectionStateChangedEventArgs(ConnectionState value) {
>         this.value = value;
>     }
> }
> ```

You should make the `ConnectionState value` readonly.

---

Using braces `{}` although they might be optional will make your code less error prone.